# How to change the PDF file

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, pdf

I have created PDF file by using `php` script and `FPDF lib`. It works fine, i have created two files named `index.php` and `create_result.php` in the file `create_result.php` i have written the `php` script for pdf file. what i want is that if i changed any program in this file there is no change in pdf file. my confusion is how to change the pdf file ,

```
ex:(result.pdf).
```

In the result.pdf file i have made a registraion form , if i want to change any thing in this result.pdf in the sense what should i do for a change?

Comment: "can any one say clearly" in a question like this must be a sarcasm, right?

Comment: PDF has no place online, and is inferior to other formats for the applications it _is_ somewhat suited for.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Does the Server have the permission to overwrite the PDF
2. Do you write Data from you login-Script into the PDF? If so, you have serious problems with multithreading, becaus one user can change the PDF for another user. You have to write a temporal PDF-File per user, with a unique filename.